# simple while loop error

Tags: c, loops, while-loop

My code is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>
main() {
    int a[10] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7};
    int i = 0;
    int c;
    while (   ((c = a[i]) != 1)   ||  (c != 0)   )
    {   
        printf("%d\t", a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

My output is:

> 2 3   4   5   0   3   4   1   6   7   0   0   0   0   2146884437  32562   -1440495800 32764   -1440495800 32764   0   1   4195741 0   0   0728816842  -394539994  4195504 0   -1440495808 32764   0   0   0   0   -1483678518 394434657   -1653941046 371143627   0   0   0   0   0   0   4195920 0   -1440495800 32764   1   0   0   0   0   0   4195504 0   -1440495808 32764   0   0   4195545 0   -1440495816 32764   28  0   1   0   -1440487321 32764   0   0   -1440487313 32764   -1440487270 32764   -1440487045 32764   -1440487002 32764   -1440486991 32764   -1440486965 32764   -1440486943 32764   -1440486925 32764-1440486899    32764   -1440486857 32764   -1440486833 32764   -1440486822 32764   -1440486792 32764   -1440486754 32764   -1440486642 32764   -1440486627 32764   -1440486616 32764   -1440486573 32764   -1440486548 32764   -1440486395 32764   -1440486374 32764   -1440486359 32764-1440486330    32764   -1440486303 ....

until seg fault.

The output should print out the values of `a` until hitting the first `0`, what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while statement 
`while (   ((c = a[i]) != 1)   ||  (c != 0)   )` 
will continue looping forever because if it is one it can't be zero and if it is zero it can't be one 
I believe what you are trying to do can be accomplished by replacing the "or" `||` with an "and" `&&` conditional operator. 
This will make the loop stop whenever `c` is equal to one or zero.
The loop will then become

```
int i = 0;
int c;
while (   ((c = a[i]) != 1)   &&  (c != 0)   )
{   printf("%d\t", a[i]);
    i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using 'and' instead of 'or' should fix it:

```
while (   ((c = a[i]) != 1)   &&  (c != 0)   )
```

With 'or' your code says if c != 0 OR you have a valid index so it keeps on going past the end of your array because one of the conditions is true (c != 0) so the whole statement is true.

Accessing memory outside of your array is never a good thing and results in unpredictable behavior. I would recommend using a for loop instead with a bound on the size of the array.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, ( if you want to stop on 0 or 1 ) it works :

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    main() {
    int a[10] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7};
    int i = 0;
    int c;
    while (   ((c = a[i]) != 1)   &&  (c != 0)   )
    {   printf("%d\t", a[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
    }
```